# gitignore and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm processing my first app with ruby on rails ! But i've got a problem. When i create my app with rails new app_name, the rails command creates a lot of files, as gitignore. But i can't find this file anywhere ! And i need this file to use 'git add .' after.
So anybody knows where it could be ? I'm stuck because by the way i can't use git status or git commit and i can't add anything to my app, this is really annoying.

I precise that i've installed git.

When I use 'git add.', the command tells me that we 'can't use gitignore as an exclude file'. I don't know what that means.

Is anybody can help me ? :) I'd appreciate that :)

Thanks you !

Justine

Comment: What operating system do you use? `.gitignore` is a hidden file by default, it is responsible for telling git which files are to be ignored by git. Obviously, .gitignore itself cannot be ignored, and it seems your .gitignore includes itself in the ignored files list.

Comment: I use OSX El Capitan. Actually i'd like to edit gitignore to make himself ignore logs, db and tmp but i can't find a way to access to this file. And I don't really understand ProgNoob's answer. I don't know what Ubuntu is.

Comment: Ubuntu is another operating system, part of Linux family. It is just like OSX or windows (just much much much better). What editor do you normally use, do you know how to open the terminal in OSX?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text, i know how to use it and i also know how to open the terminal in osx and use it. I only have a problem with gitignore :( I tried what the other person has suggested me and i can edit it but there's no way i can exit from there. I don't know if i'm clear, maybe i explain to you my problem the wrong way :/

Comment: Well, basicaly this question doesn't really belong to this site, as this is not strictly programming issue. Have a look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64324/how-do-i-get-sublime-texts-open-file-gui-to-show-hidden-files. AFAK, when creating new rails application .gitignore should already contain logs and other stuff.

Comment: Okay, thanks i'll take a look at it :)